# What is the difference between an algorithm and a function?

Tags: algorithm, function, terminology

Are they the same thing?

Comment: What's the difference between a recipe and a delicious cake?

Comment: More clarity should be given about what is asked. Are you referring to mathematical function, or imperative function?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No.

A function is a block of code in a computer program.

An algorithm is an abstract concept that describes how to solve a problem.

Comment: unfortunately there is no formal and precise definition of algorithm. By Church-Turing thesis, there is an universally accepted definition which is informal. Even CLRS start with saying "Informally an algorithm is...". Even this answer states "abstract concept" which is quite ambiguous.

Comment: I would argue that a function is a mathematical concept, and not necessarily related to a computer program, although we also use something called functions in computer programming. As far as I know, the mathematical function -- as a concept -- was introduced long before computer programming with functions existed.

Comment: @runeks, considering the fact that this is a website for programming related questions, I would consider that fact pretty irrelevant.

Comment: it's the other way around lol

Comment: This question is not the correct answer in any case, is rude, and arrogant.

Answer (score 16):

In mathematics, a function is "a mathematical relation such that each element of a given set (the domain of the function) is associated with an element of another set (the range of the function)" (source - google.com, define:function).

In computer science, a function is a piece of code that optionally takes parameters, optionally gives a result, and optionally has a side effect (depending on the language - some languages forbid side-effects).  It must have a specific machine implementation in order to execute.

The computer science term came out of the mathematical term, being the machine implementation of the mathematical concept.

An algorithm is "a precise rule (or set of rules) specifying how to solve some problem" (source - google.com, define:algorithm).  An algorithm can be defined outside of computer science, and does not have a definitive machine implementation.  You can "implement" it by writing it out by hand :)

The key difference here is, in computer science, an algorithm is abstract, and doesn't have a definitive machine implementation.  A function is concrete, and does have a machine implementation.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. "function" can mean a unit of code as implemented in a particular language. It can also mean an abstract, functional definition of computation, based on the model of the lambda calculus.

Comment: this is the better answer.

Answer (score 7):

An algorithm is a set of instructions.

In computer programming, a function is an implementation of an algorithm.

Comment: a _set_ is an ambiguous word here, though it probably can be clarified.

Comment: In computer programming, a function *can be* an implementation of an algorithm, it can also simply update state, or even only do input or output.

Answer (score 4):

An algorithm is a series of steps (a process) for performing a calculation, whereas a function is the mathematical relationship between parameters and results.

A function in programming is different than the typical, mathematical meaning of function because it's a set of instructions implementing an algorithm for calculating a function.

Answer (score 3):

An algorithm describes the general idea, whereas a function is an actual working implementation of that idea.

Answer (score 2):

It might be almost a philosophical question, but I'de say an algorithm is the answer(or how-to) to a problem at hand where as a function does not necerally answer one problem in itself.

What you want to do normally is split your algorithm into severals function that each has their own goal, which, in the end, will achieve the problem at hand, when used together.

Ex : You want to Sort a list of numbers. The algorightm used would be for example the Merge-sort algorithm. That specific algorithm is actually composed of more than one functions, one that will split your array, another to check for equality, another to merge everything back together, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

A mathematical function is the interface, or specification of the inputs and outputs of an algorithm.

An algorithm is the precise recipe that defines the steps that may implement a function.

Confusingly, computer language designers diffuse this distinction by using the concept `function`, `func`, `method`, etc, to talk about both concepts.

So the distinction is one of specification vs. definition.

There is also a semantic distinction: an algorithm seeks to provide a solution to a problem. It is goal-oriented. A function simply *is* - there is no essential teleological component.

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm is the implementation of a function.

In some cases, the algorithm is trivial:

Function: Sum of two numbers.
Algorithm:
`int sum(int x, int y){
  return x+y;
}`

In other cases, it is not:

Function: Best chess move.
Algorithm:
`Move bestChessMove(State gameState){
   //I don't know the algorithm.
}`

Comment: The algorithm may be just pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm is a (possibly informal but necessarily precise) *sequence of instructions*. Function is a *formal rule* that associates some input w/ a specific output. Functions implement and formalize algorithms. E.g. we can formalize "go from a to b" as `go(a)=b` or `go(x,a)=b` (w/ `x` the one who goes), etc. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm),

> An algorithm is an effective method that can be expressed within a
>   finite amount of space and time and in a well-defined formal
>   language for calculating a function.

So you can say that "go(ing) from a to b" is an effective method for calculating `go(a)=b` (if you want)

Answer (score -1):

An Algorithm usually refers to the method or process used to end up with the result after mathematical processing. A Function is a subroutine used to avoid writing the same code over and over again. They are different in their uses. For instance, there may be an Algorithm that is used for encrypting data, and a function for posting code to a webpage.

Here is some further reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(computer_science)

Answer (score -1):

A function is a symbolic representation whereare a method is the mechanical steps needed to get the answer.

Suppose this function:

```
f(x) = x^ 2
```

Now if I tell you to count `f(5000)` you have to do things that this function doesn't say. Like for example how to multiply. So really these are just symbols.

But if I have a python method for example:

```
x = math.pow(500, 2) # or whatever it is
```

Then in this case the steps themselves for each operation are totally defined (in the libraries ;) ).